# How should I implement my Parcel details interface out of the two implementations?

Tags: c#

I have an XML document from which I would be reading data and I have to implement an interface for it. Below is the sample XML:

```
    <Parcel>
      <Sender>
        <Name>Klaas</Name>
        <Address>
          <Street>Uranusstraat</Street>
          <HouseNumber>22</HouseNumber>
          <PostalCode>2402AE</PostalCode>
          <City>Alphen a/d Rijn</City>
        </Address>
      </Sender>
      <Receipient>
        <Name>Piet</Name>
        <Address>
          <Street>Schenklaan</Street>
          <HouseNumber>22</HouseNumber>
          <PostalCode>2497AV</PostalCode>
          <City>Den Haag</City>
        </Address>
      </Receipient>
      <Weight>0.02</Weight>
      <Value>0.0</Value>
    </Parcel>
```

How should I create my Interface?

First way:

```
   interface IAddress
   {
      string Street {get; set;}
      int HouseNumber {get; set;}
      string PostalCode {get; set;}
      string City {get; set;}
   }

   interface ISender : IAddress
   {
      string Name {get; set;}
      IAddress SenderAddress {get; set;}
   }

   interface IReceipient : IAddress
   {
      string Name {get; set;}
      IAddress ReceipientAddress {get; set;}
   }

   interface IParcel : ISender, IReceipient
   {
      ISender Sender {get; set;}
      IReceipeint Receipient {get; set;}
   }
```

Second Way:

```
   interface IParcelDetails
    {
        string SenderName { get; set; }
        string SenderStreet { get; set; }
        int SenderHouseNumber { get; set; }
        string SenderPostalCode { get; set; }
        string SenderCity { get; set; }
        string ReceipientName { get; set; }
        string ReceipientStreet { get; set; }
        int ReceipientHouseNumber { get; set; }
        string ReceipientPostalCode { get; set; }
        string ReceipientCity { get; set; }
    }
```

But, I am not sure how should I have to implement the `IParcel` interface in my class if I have to use the first approach.

Part 2: (Update)
Based on the weight I have to choose a department

- Parcels with a weight of up to 1 kg are handled by the "Mail" department.
- Parcels with a weight of up to 10 kg are handled by the "Regular" department.
- Parcels with a weight over 10 kg are handled by the "Heavy" department.

I am using Factory Design Pattern to accomplish this functionality but how should I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the first way, but you'd have to adapt your interfaces a bit.

```cs
interface IAddress
{
    string Street { get; set; }
    int HouseNumber { get; set; }
    string PostalCode { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
}

interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IAddress Address { get; set; }
}

interface IParcel
{
    IPerson Sender { get; set; }
    IPerson Receipient { get; set; }
    double Weight { get; set; }
    double Value { get; set; }
}

interface IDepartment
{
    IList<IParcel> Parcels { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; } // Or Type, whatever you want
}
```

Another option for your department types would be an enum:

```cs
interface IDepartment
{
    IList<IParcel> Parcels { get; set; }
    DepartmentType Type { get; set; }
}

enum DepartmentType
{
    Mail,
    Regular,
    Heavy
}
```

Then you would create a separate class for each interface. So in the end you'll have three classes: `Department`, `Parcel`, `Person` and `Address`

Comment: Why do I need to create a separate class? Can't I use the IParcel interface to get access to the rest of the properties in the interface?

Comment: You could (if you have a parser for it), but in the name of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) please don't ;)
This way you avoid duplicate code and improve the readability.

Comment: One thing, let's say I want to 4 departments where I want to implement Parcel details, so how would I proceed further on this case? Do I have to create another class which would be inherited by my rest of the department classes?

Comment: Can you add it to your question, I'm not sure if I understood you right

Comment: If I understood you right, you'd have to implement a class for the Department and add a property which contains the parcels / parcel